# Code Revision Control Software to Handle Cross-Platform Projects

Tags: cross-platform

is there a code revision control software to handle cross platform projects?

I am talking about handling two platform-specific source code (for instance, one in Java and one in C) of the same conceptual software to do things like keeping track of the changes to the same conceptual part in both code base etc.

Answer (score 0):

Any version control software (aka revision control software) can handle source code from different languages, for different platforms. (But the question isn't very clear, so I'm not entirely sure what's being asked.)

If you have a single project with some bits coded in C and others in Java, that's not a problem -- and it has nothing to do w/ the revision control software being used. Just organize your directories so that you build your C code w/ "make" (or cmake or whatever), and your Java app with maven (or ant or whatever), and (optionally) create a third project that packages/bundles your jars with your native libraries for distribution.  Then use git (or svn or hg or whatever) to track changes to the project.  Nothing special here; many projects do exactly this.

Comment: To clarify the question, assume you have 2 calculators: One is written in Java, and the other is written in C. Is there a revision software that helps me to map one block of code in Java to another block of code in C and vice verse, and helps me track not only one application's life time but also life time of a couple of applications with respect to each other (again the applications here are not arbitrary applications, but they do the same conceptual job, but their code base is in different languages).